# How could I get values from array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a php array like this:

```
array(
[0] =>
array(
... 3 elements ... )

['cat'] =>
'FF'
...
['iPath'] =>
'http://www.xx.com/images'
...
['dispName'] =>
'Fast Food'
...
)
[1] =>
array(
... 3 elements ... )

['cat'] =>
'G&L'
...
['iPath'] =>
'http://www.xx.com/images'
...
['dispName'] =>
'Grocery & Liquor'
...
)
[2] =>
array(
... 3 elements ... )

['cat'] =>
'Gas'
...
['iPath'] =>
'http://www.xx.com/images'
...
['dispName'] =>
'Gas Stations'
...
) 
)
```

I want to be able to get the values for: iPath and dispName when cat = XXX. For instance, when cat = 'G&L'.

thanks

ldj

Comment: please format your post using the <pre> and <code> tags. Do you want to find the array which has a value of 'Gas' for the key 'cat'?

Comment: Is that array from `print_r()`? It looks wrong to me, somehow. And I don't know *why*. O.o @zzzzBov, it's easier to select the code and hit `ctrl + K` (or hit the `101010` button). Still, good advice. @ldj: please look at: [Stackoverflow Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: There is no key Gas in your array?

Comment: @Rajani is right. Did you mean to ask how to get the keys that have Gas as the value? Further, do you mean exactly "Gas", or containing Gas (like "Gas Stations")?

Comment: I have edited to post to be clear. I thank you all for the valuable recommendations and for the willingness to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. I don't understand anything from your example code.

B. To get array values in PHP you can use both numeric key values and string key values. Any of the following is valid:

```
$arr[1][7][0]
$arr['key1'][2]
$arr['42'][42]
$arr['keyLevel1']['keyLevel2']
```

Also note that `$arr[42]` will address the same element as `$arr['42']`.

C. Here's some recommended reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

---

A'. To find the keys for all the `Gas` values in the array.

```
function findGasInArray($arr){
    $results = Array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if($val == 'Gas')
            $results[] = Array($key);
        if(is_array($val)){
            foreach(findGasInArray($val) as $otherVal){
                array_unshift($otherVal, $key);
                $results[] = $otherVal;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
findAllGasInArray($myBigArray);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he actually mean. I think he actually meant almost the opposite (how to get keys for values which match some condition), but was just mixing up terminology, like zzzzBov suggested in the comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this. Assuming your array is named $arr, then do this:

```
$indexes = array_filter(function($i) { return $arr[i]['cat'] == 'Gas'; }, array_keys($arr));
```

Comment: So you assume that `Gas` will always be at the key `cat`? I don't really get what you're trying to do. If he indeed wants to find the keys with value `Gas` and his array has depth level bigger than one then he needs to walk the array recursively.

Comment: @Alin, based on how I understood the question (which I admit I may have misunderstood), it looks like it is valid to assume the "Gas" will always be at "cat" and no other key. I assume "cat" stands for category and "Gas" is a fixed category name.

Comment: @Alin, and I suspect ldj was trying to find all members of the array that have the "Gas" set for "cat" (looking for the indexes of all gas stations). That's what my code snippet does.

Comment: sometimes helping people is the reward.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I know, I did answer after all. I was tempted not to but I blocked that temptation. Also, even if the OP doesn't accept it, it's still useful for anyone else that comes across it later. It's just slightly annoying when someone gains from the community but doesn't even bother to leave positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[2]['cat']
```